# Azure Logic App and Data Flow - Remove ? and @ from JSON (XML)

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-data-factory

I have created a Logic App that converts XML to JSON

[LogicAppProcess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KkmA.png)

This work 'great', no issues in that part of the process - however, this retains some ? and @ symbols within some of the column names. This is then not working downstream in an Azure Data Flow as the @ symbol is being picked up a parameter..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSM58.png)

```
{"code":"BadRequest","message":"ErrorCode=InvalidTemplate, ErrorMessage=Unable to parse expression 'version'","target":"pipeline/PL_XXXX/runid/XXXX","details":null,"error":null}
```

Any ideas as to how i can either replace the ? and @ symbols at the first point in the process (Logic App) or accommodate for these in the Data Flow?

This is how the Data Flow code sees the error in the Script element - the ?xml is not throwing an error but the first @ is, and shows @version as the error

```
"script": "source(output(\n\t\t{?xml} as ({@version} as string, {@encoding} as string),\n\t\trss as ({@version} as string, {@xmlns:cisAbstract} as string...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [replace()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#replace) function in your logic app to replace the `?` and `@` with null string `""`. If your data is not string type(such as json object or array or any other type), you can use [string()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#string) function to convert them to string first and then do the replace() function. Shown as below expression:

```
replace(replace(string(<your data>), '@', ''), '?', '')
```